# Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner

Tags: flink-streaming

When I run a **SocketWindowWordCount** Program in Apache flink, it shows a

**WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner**

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
>   (file:/home/aman.srivastava/Downloads/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.10.0.jar) to field java.lang.String.value WARNING: Please consider reporting
>   this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable
>   warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release Job has been submitted with JobID
>   a4badaa76080e47e82a322a4e2060e45

Answer (score 9):

This warning is because you probably use Java 11. Flink docs says:

> These warnings are considered harmless and will be addressed in future Flink releases.

You can find more here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/release-notes/flink-1.10.html#java-11-support-flink-10725

Comment: Not very harmless, since the warning becomes an error in OpenJDK >= 17