# WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner

Tags: apache-flink

This warning become unproductive for our project.
we are using flink and it is producing the below warning.

Due to this warning redis functionality is not working, not able to add and update sorted set in Redis.

Apache Flink version 1.17 and apache-flink/1.17.0/libexec/lib/flink-dist-1.17.0.jar) to field java.lang.String.value

Can someone from Apache Flink team take this on priority.

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Due to this warning redis functionality is not working".

Comment: If you want someone from the Flink community to work on a problem you've found, you need to file an issue in Jira.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search in StackOverflow shows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754821/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-apache-flink-api-java-closurecleaner) as the number one hit for this exact same issue. You'll need to add more information about this, as to why this behavior is causing an actual problem for you, as it seems to me to be a beginning warning.

Comment: We are using valueOf method multiple times in our redis functionality to convert value from Double to Integer and Double to String, valueOf uses internally reflective api for the conversion hence we are not getting proper result based on above warning. we have deployed our jar in flink environment then only creating this issues. if we run java program without flink environment that it will work as per expected. we are using java 8 for running java program and flink uses java11.